# Problem with str.isdigit() in if condition

Tags: python

I need to make calculations only when some particular imputs are integers higher than 1 and lower than 5. If numbers do not meet this condition a message is printed. It works.
I wanted the message to be printed also when the imput is not an integer but it doesn't work. When I type for example "a" I got info "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'ds'"

```
w = input("write a number")
if (int(w)<1 or int(w)>5) or w.isdigit()==False:
    print("input must be between 1 and 5 and not to be a letter")
else:
    print(w)
```

Comment: That's likely because you cannot cast a non-numeric expression into an integer. Note that, if 'w' is not a number, 'int(w)' will throw an error.

Comment: As an aside, you can express this a little more naturally as `if not w.isdigit() or not 1 <= int(w) <= 5:`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `w` is indeed not a number, then `int(w)` won't work and you'll get the error you're describing. However, you're already checking if `w` is a number, you just have to order the conditions the other way round:

```
w = input("write a number")
if w.isdigit() == False or int(w) < 1 or int(w) > 5:
    print("input must be between 1 and 5 and not to be a letter")
else:
    print(w)
```

The conditions are evaluated from left to right, so if `w.isdigit() == False` is the case, `int(w) < 1` and `int(w) > 5` won't even be evaluated and you won't see the error.

Comment: Note: Idiomatically, `w.isdigit() == False` is bad code; basically any comparison to `True` or `False` is wrong. Replace it with `not w.isdigit()`. You can also reorganize the conversion and range check to avoid a double conversion, making the test `if not w.isdigit() or not (1 <= int(w) <= 5):`. To be clear, this answer is correct and matches the OP, but the original code was not idiomatic, and could be easily improved.

Comment: Of course, even more idiomatic would be to use EAFP instead of `.isdigit()` testing  (which rejects some things `int` would accept, e.g. strings with leading/trailing whitespace). `try:`, `w = int(w)` `except ValueError:` `print("input is not an integer")`, then test `if not 1 <= w <= 5: print("input is not between 1 and 5")`

Answer (score 1):

The problem arises because of the manner in which the `or` operator functions. Actually, when you have two or more `or`s then the compiler keeps on checking the conditions until it gets the first `False`.

In your case, when you enter a letter(say 'a') then the condition `w.isdigit()` is checked in the end and so `int()` gives the error `invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'` . So to avoid the error, simply change the order of the conditions. First check whether the input is a digit or not and then check for the range as follows:

```
w = input("write a number")
if  w.isdigit()==False or (int(w)<1 or int(w)>5) :
    print("input must be between 1 and 5 and not to be a letter")
else:
    print(w)
```